# Я и так знаю (,) у кого

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, корректно ли в данном случае отсутствие запятой:
— Давай узнаем, у кого остались эти вещи.
— Я и так знаю(,) у кого.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно. Вопрос, пожалуй, обратный: можно ли эту запятую сохранить...

В случае, когда союзное слово можно трактовать как член главного предложения, оно не рассматривается как присоединяющее придаточное, то есть придаточного как бы и нет вовсе. Такое происходит всегда, когда при таком союзном слове нет зависимых слов.

> в) если придаточная часть усечена до одного союзного слова (одиночно
>   употребленное союзное слово теряет функцию придаточного предложения):
>   Учащимся назначили экзамен, но не уточнили когда; Со стороны проспекта
>   кто-то шел — издали было неясно кто (Пелев.);

(ПАС Лопатина, § 115, примечания) 
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=384

На самом деле есть два других вопроса: 1. А корректна ли в этом случае запятая, то есть можно ли рассматривать само слово как придаточное? 2. Есть ли случаи, когда запятую можно опустить по подобным мотивам при том, что в потенциальном придаточном более одного слова?

Вот на эти вопросы очень трудно дать исчерпывающий ответ.  Но мне кажется, что в отдельных случаях запятая всё-таки возможна - как авторский интонационный знак. То есть, если автор хочет подчеркнуть акцент на "у кого", то запятая возможна (личное мнение).

Но уж без неё-то точно не будет ошибкой - по основному правилу.

***Давай узнаем, у кого остались эти вещи. — Я и так знаю у кого.***